# CSS: Horizontal, comma-separated list with fixed <li> width

Tags: css, inline, fixed-width, horizontallist

I would like to achieve the following structure:

```
[gfhtfg..., kgjrfg..., asd,      mrhgf,   ]  
 ^-------^  ^-------^  ^-------^ ^-------^  
     X          X          X         X
(X = a fixed length)
```

I've got a `<div>` with a fixed length, and inside it an horizontal, comma-separated list (`ul`) of links.
The `<li>` elements should have a fixed width, and so if the links exceed a fixed length an ellipsis will be shown (using the `text-overflow` property).

I know two ways to make a list horizontal. One is using `display: inline` and the other using the `float` property.

- With the first approach, I can't set a fixed width because the CSS specification doesn't allow setting the width of inline elements.
- The second approach creates a mess :O
- Setting `float` on the `<a>` element, intending to limit the width there, separates it from the commas.

*There are no browser-compatibility issues, I only have to support WebKit.*

I included the code I attempted to work with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>a title</title>
 <style>
  body { font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt; }

  div {
   height: 30px;
   width: 300px;
   background: #eee;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   text-align: center;
  }

  ul { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
  ul li:after { content: ","; }
  ul li:last-child:after { content: ""; }
  ul li a { text-decoration: none; color: #666; }

  ul li {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-text-overflow: ellipsis;
   /* Inline elements can't have a width (and they shouldn't according to the specification */
   display: inline;
   width: 30px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">a certain link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">once again</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">another one</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
...
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none; color: #666; 
 display: inline-block; 
 max-width: 50px; /* 'X' minus gutter */
 white-space: nowrap; 
 text-overflow: ellipsis; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60px; /* 'X' */
}
...
```

My 2¢

Comment: Which bit generates the commas?

Comment: The `ul li:after`-part in the original post. I just rewrote the `ul li` and `ul li a`, the rest are the same.

Comment: Used this in my project. Thanks for teaching me about inline-block.

Answer (score 3):

Set the 'display' attribute of the li elements to 'inline-block'. It is fully compatible with WebKit browsers. You cannot give an inline level element dimensions, but you can to a block level element. inline-block is a happy medium in your case - it allows dimensions but displays inline. It is a better alternative to floats and clears too I think.

Comment: Doh! Beat me to it by a minute. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [display: inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) and set a fixed width? This allows you to have inline elements that can be sized, just like an `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `display: inline-block` before, but if the links had spaces in them the words would break into a new line.
Further random searching revealed that `white-space: nowrap;` fixes that problem, and so the final solution is to add these properties to the `<li>` element:

```
ul li {
 width: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Thank you for your replies.

**EDIT: Actually, the commas are not displayed.

Removing the `overflow` and `text-overflow` properties reveals that the `<li>` elements overlap, and that the commas are hidden with the rest of the text.**

Comment: I am starting to sound like a broken record, but for cross-browser support with `inline-block`, you'll want the following styles: `display: -moz-inline-box` (Firefox < 3; it's not identical but it's close for most uses) and for elements which are block-level by default IE 6 and IE 7 don't support `inline-block`, but `display: inline` plus `hasLayout` (which can be had with `zoom: 1` without side-effect) is identical to `inline-block` in those browsers. (You can use `*display: inline; *zoom: 1;` to isolate those browsers, or you can include those styles with conditional comments.)

Comment: Author said "There are no browser-compatibility issues, I only have to support WebKit."

Comment: @0scar, ah I didn't notice that. Still I'll leave the comment for others who happen on this post; it's missed often enough that I find myself making note of it on SO probably twice a month.